# Folder moving events in google drive

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api, google-drive-shared-drive, google-drive-picker

When I drag a folder to another location,

is there any way I could know this activity, telling me that it is from where to where?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Google Drive Activity API](https://developers.google.com/drive/activity/v2) to get informations about the changes made within a user's Google Drive.

**Using [activity.query()](https://developers.google.com/drive/activity/v2/reference/rest/v2/activity/query):**

- Set the `itemName` based on the file/folder that you want to check activity using this format `"items/FILE_ID"` or `"items/FOLDER_ID"`
- Set `filter` to `detail.action_detail_case:MOVE` to get move action activities

**References:**

- [Making Requests in the Drive Activity API](https://developers.google.com/drive/activity/v2/requests#filtering)
- [Filtering](https://developers.google.com/drive/activity/v2/requests#filtering)

---

### **Sample Request Body:**

```
{
  "filter": "detail.action_detail_case:MOVE",
  "itemName": "items/1BNPRFAJgVMW-DF_sdEsF-_14X0xxxxx"
}
```

- Filter all drive activity that has `move` [ActionDetail](http://ActionDetail)
- Primary criteria is to return activities for a specific folder with `folder id: 1BNPRFAJgVMW-DF_sdEsF-_14X0xxxxx`

---

### Response Body:

This will return a [DriveActivity](https://developers.google.com/drive/activity/v2/reference/rest/v2/activity/driveactivity#DriveActivity) object that will contain a [Move](https://developers.google.com/drive/activity/v2/reference/rest/v2/activity/move#Move) object under [ActionDetail](https://developers.google.com/drive/activity/v2/reference/rest/v2/activity/actiondetail#actiondetail) object. You can refer to the `removedParents`->`driveItem` to get the information regarding the previous parent folder of the file/folder and `addedParents`->`driveItem` to get the new parent folder of the file/folder

```
{
  "activities": [
    {
      "primaryActionDetail": {
        "move": {
          "addedParents": [
            {
              "driveItem": {
                "name": "items/1mF5a3gxiLzVIRe2dhY4W3Alfxxxx",
                "title": "NewFolder_Name",
                "folder": {
                  "type": "STANDARD_FOLDER"
                },
                "driveFolder": {
                  "type": "STANDARD_FOLDER"
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          "removedParents": [
            {
              "driveItem": {
                "name": "items/1lFzVvlBnBi-2o1VQGF5JDFRxxxxx",
                "title": "TESTFOLDER",
                "folder": {
                  "type": "STANDARD_FOLDER"
                },
                "driveFolder": {
                  "type": "STANDARD_FOLDER"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
        
      .....
        
      "targets": [
        {
          "driveItem": {
            "name": "items/11TrX6KcAJppWCj9GSUjSYn79Aqxxxx",
            "title": "CSVFOLDER",
            "folder": {
              "type": "STANDARD_FOLDER"
            },
            "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder",
            .......
          }
        }
      ],
      "timestamp": "2021-08-12T16:10:24.744Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: but could i not do any request, and when there is such activity , it push the notification to me directly?

Comment: You can use drive api [push notification](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/push) to check if changes are done in your drive folder. Then trigger your application to call drive activity to check if a folder was moved inside your root folder. Basically instead of using `itemName` in your drive activity query() you can use `ancestorName` and use your root folder id to get all move activity within your folder